# How to create link to a data-filter element?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have [this website][1] made in Wordpress.

It's there any way to link the blue icons to the data-filter of the portfolio?
I want to sort the portfolio gallery via blue icons. My problem is that the wordpress theme is written in shortcode and it's really hard for me to understand and modify the code. I've tried to create a link like below and afterto put it in the pagebuilder in the sections of the icons, but it doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong.

```
<script>
    var filterFromQuerystring = getParameterByName('filter');
    $('a[data-filter=".' + filterFromQuerystring  + '"]').click();
</script>
```

```html
<p>[vc_row type="full_width_background" full_screen_row_position="middle" bg_color="#3a6ee8" scene_position="center" text_color="light" text_align="left" top_padding="8%" bottom_padding="3%" color_overlay="#3a6ee8" overlay_strength="0.3" enable_shape_divider="true" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type="curve"][vc_column column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/1" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_custom_heading text="Împreună am construit toate tipurile de clădiri" font_container="tag:h2|text_align:center" use_theme_fonts="yes"][vc_row_inner column_margin="default" text_align="left"][vc_column_inner column_padding="padding-4-percent" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/3" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_custom_heading text="Proiectat" font_container="tag:h5|text_align:center|color:rgba(255%2C255%2C255%2C0.7)" use_theme_fonts="yes" css_animation="fadeIn"][milestone heading_inherit="h2" subject_padding="2%" color="Default" effect="count" milestone_alignment="default" number="3" subject="Milioane Metri Pătrați" number_font_size="92"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner column_padding="padding-4-percent" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/3" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_custom_heading text="Urbanizat" font_container="tag:h5|text_align:center|color:rgba(255%2C255%2C255%2C0.7)" use_theme_fonts="yes" css_animation="fadeIn"][milestone heading_inherit="h2" subject_padding="2%" color="Default" effect="count" milestone_alignment="default" number="16" subject="Mii Hectare" number_font_size="92"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner column_padding="padding-4-percent" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/3" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_custom_heading text="Construit" font_container="tag:h5|text_align:center|color:rgba(255%2C255%2C255%2C0.7)" use_theme_fonts="yes" css_animation="fadeIn"][milestone heading_inherit="h2" subject_padding="2%" color="Default" effect="count" milestone_alignment="default" number="37" number_font_size="92" subject="Proiecte"][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="full_width_background" full_screen_row_position="middle" scene_position="center" text_color="dark" text_align="center" top_padding="3%" bottom_padding="7%" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type="curve"][vc_column enable_animation="true" animation="grow-in" centered_text="true" column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/6" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][nectar_icon icon_family="iconsmind" icon_style="default" icon_color="Accent-Color" icon_padding="15px" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Keypad"][vc_column_text]</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #3a6ee8;">Rezidențial</span></p>
<p>[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][vc_column enable_animation="true" animation="grow-in" centered_text="true" column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/6" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid" delay="500"][nectar_icon icon_family="iconsmind" icon_style="default" icon_color="Accent-Color" icon_padding="20px" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Shop-2"][vc_column_text]</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #3a6ee8;">Comercial</span></p>
<p>[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][vc_column enable_animation="true" animation="grow-in" centered_text="true" column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/6" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid" delay="1000"][nectar_icon icon_family="iconsmind" icon_style="default" icon_color="Accent-Color" icon_padding="20px" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Hotel"][vc_column_text]</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #3a6ee8;">Birouri</span></p>
<p>[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][vc_column enable_animation="true" animation="grow-in" centered_text="true" column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/6" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid" delay="1500"][nectar_icon icon_family="iconsmind" icon_style="default" icon_color="Accent-Color" icon_padding="20px" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Factory"][vc_column_text]</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #3a6ee8;">Industrial</span></p>
<p>[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][vc_column enable_animation="true" animation="grow-in" centered_text="true" column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/6" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid" delay="2000"][nectar_icon icon_family="iconsmind" icon_style="default" icon_color="Accent-Color" icon_padding="20px" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Map"][vc_column_text]</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #3a6ee8;">Urbanistic</span></p>
<p>[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][vc_column enable_animation="true" animation="grow-in" centered_text="true" column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/6" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid" delay="2500"][nectar_icon icon_family="iconsmind" icon_style="default" icon_color="Accent-Color" icon_padding="20px" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Green-House"][vc_column_text]</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #3a6ee8;">Special</span></p>
<p>[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="full_width_background" full_screen_row_position="middle" scene_position="top" layer_one_image="6038" layer_two_image="6034" text_color="dark" text_align="left" top_padding="1%" bottom_padding="1%" disable_element="yes" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type=""][vc_column column_padding="padding-3-percent" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="5/12" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_column_text css=".vc_custom_1517436123174{margin-top: 50px !important;margin-bottom: 20px !important;}"]</p>
<h5><span style="color: #999999;">Proiect no.1</span></h5>
<h2>Coresi Shopping Resort</h2>
<p>[/vc_column_text][nectar_icon_list animate="true" color="default" icon_size="small" icon_style="no-border"][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517435668816-0-5" tab_id="1517435668820-10" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Shop-2" header="Comercial"][/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517434471-1-58" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="60 000 m2" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Background"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517435114965-0-4" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="2015" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Key"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" title="List Item" id="1517434471-2-33" tab_id="1517434693099-10" icon_fontawesome="fa fa-briefcase" header="Immochan Imobiliare"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517435106511-0-9" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="Strada Turnului, Brasov" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Map2"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][/nectar_icon_list][/vc_column][vc_column enable_animation="true" animation="grow-in" centered_text="true" column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="7/12" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid" delay="100"][nectar_cascading_images image_1_url="6078" image_1_offset_x_sign="-" image_1_offset_x="15%" image_1_offset_y_sign="+" image_1_offset_y="25%" image_1_rotate_sign="+" image_1_rotate="none" image_1_animation="Grow In" image_1_box_shadow="x_large_depth" image_2_url="6070" image_2_offset_x_sign="+" image_2_offset_x="65%" image_2_offset_y_sign="+" image_2_offset_y="15%" image_2_rotate_sign="+" image_2_rotate="none" image_2_animation="Grow In" image_2_box_shadow="x_large_depth" image_3_url="6079" image_3_offset_x_sign="+" image_3_offset_x="35%" image_3_offset_y_sign="-" image_3_offset_y="50%" image_3_rotate_sign="+" image_3_rotate="none" image_3_animation="Grow In" image_3_box_shadow="x_large_depth" image_4_offset_x_sign="+" image_4_offset_x="0%" image_4_offset_y_sign="+" image_4_offset_y="0%" image_4_rotate_sign="+" image_4_rotate="none" image_4_animation="Fade In" image_4_box_shadow="none" border_radius="none" animation_timing="500"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="in_container" full_screen_row_position="middle" scene_position="center" text_color="dark" text_align="left" disable_element="yes" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type=""][vc_column column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/1" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][divider line_type="Full Width Line" line_thickness="1" divider_color="default" animate="yes"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="full_width_background" full_screen_row_position="middle" equal_height="yes" content_placement="middle" scene_position="top" layer_one_image="6038" layer_two_image="6034" text_color="dark" text_align="left" top_padding="1%" bottom_padding="1%" disable_element="yes" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type=""][vc_column column_padding="padding-3-percent" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="7/12" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][nectar_cascading_images image_1_url="6076" image_1_offset_x_sign="+" image_1_offset_x="0%" image_1_offset_y_sign="-" image_1_offset_y="55%" image_1_rotate_sign="+" image_1_rotate="none" image_1_animation="Grow In" image_1_box_shadow="none" image_2_url="6075" image_2_offset_x_sign="+" image_2_offset_x="50%" image_2_offset_y_sign="+" image_2_offset_y="35%" image_2_rotate_sign="+" image_2_rotate="none" image_2_animation="Grow In" image_2_box_shadow="none" image_3_url="6077" image_3_offset_x_sign="-" image_3_offset_x="35%" image_3_offset_y_sign="+" image_3_offset_y="30%" image_3_rotate_sign="+" image_3_rotate="none" image_3_animation="Grow In" image_3_box_shadow="x_large_depth" image_4_offset_x_sign="+" image_4_offset_x="0%" image_4_offset_y_sign="+" image_4_offset_y="0%" image_4_rotate_sign="+" image_4_rotate="none" image_4_animation="Fade In" image_4_box_shadow="none" border_radius="none"][/vc_column][vc_column column_padding="padding-6-percent" column_padding_position="left" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="5/12" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_column_text css=".vc_custom_1517438369719{margin-top: 50px !important;margin-bottom: 20px !important;}"]</p>
<h5><span style="color: #999999;">Proiect no.1</span></h5>
<h2>Green Gate</h2>
<p>[/vc_column_text][nectar_icon_list animate="true" color="default" icon_size="small" icon_style="no-border"][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517437108276-0-6" tab_id="1517435668820-10" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Hotel" header="Birouri"][/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517437108344-0-6" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="49 000 m2" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Background"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517437108417-0-3" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="2014" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Key"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" title="List Item" id="1517437108518-0-4" tab_id="1517434693099-10" icon_fontawesome="fa fa-briefcase" header="Green Gate Development"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517437108606-0-3" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="Bulevardul Tudor Vladimirescu, Bucuresti" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Map2"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][/nectar_icon_list][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="in_container" full_screen_row_position="middle" scene_position="center" text_color="dark" text_align="left" disable_element="yes" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type=""][vc_column column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/1" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][divider line_type="Full Width Line" line_thickness="1" divider_color="default" animate="yes"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="full_width_background" full_screen_row_position="middle" scene_position="top" layer_one_image="6038" layer_two_image="6034" text_color="dark" text_align="left" top_padding="1%" bottom_padding="1%" disable_element="yes" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type=""][vc_column column_padding="padding-3-percent" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="5/12" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_column_text css=".vc_custom_1517441470308{margin-top: 50px !important;margin-bottom: 20px !important;}"]</p>
<h5><span style="color: #999999;">Proiect no.3</span></h5>
<h2>Complex Comercial Cora</h2>
<p>[/vc_column_text][nectar_icon_list animate="true" color="default" icon_size="small" icon_style="no-border"][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517437108276-0-6" tab_id="1517435668820-10" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Shop-2" header="Comercial"][/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517437108344-0-6" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="85 000 m2" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Background"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517437108417-0-3" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="2013" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Key"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" title="List Item" id="1517437108518-0-4" tab_id="1517434693099-10" icon_fontawesome="fa fa-briefcase" header="Temestate"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517437108606-0-3" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="Strada Cumpenei, Constanta" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Map2"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][/nectar_icon_list][/vc_column][vc_column enable_animation="true" animation="grow-in" centered_text="true" column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="7/12" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid" delay="100"][nectar_cascading_images image_1_url="6081" image_1_offset_x_sign="+" image_1_offset_x="0%" image_1_offset_y_sign="-" image_1_offset_y="55%" image_1_rotate_sign="+" image_1_rotate="none" image_1_animation="Grow In" image_1_box_shadow="none" image_2_url="6082" image_2_offset_x_sign="+" image_2_offset_x="50%" image_2_offset_y_sign="+" image_2_offset_y="35%" image_2_rotate_sign="+" image_2_rotate="none" image_2_animation="Grow In" image_2_box_shadow="none" image_3_url="6080" image_3_offset_x_sign="-" image_3_offset_x="35%" image_3_offset_y_sign="+" image_3_offset_y="30%" image_3_rotate_sign="+" image_3_rotate="none" image_3_animation="Grow In" image_3_box_shadow="x_large_depth" image_4_offset_x_sign="+" image_4_offset_x="0%" image_4_offset_y_sign="+" image_4_offset_y="0%" image_4_rotate_sign="+" image_4_rotate="none" image_4_animation="Fade In" image_4_box_shadow="none" border_radius="none"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="in_container" full_screen_row_position="middle" scene_position="center" text_color="dark" text_align="left" disable_element="yes" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type=""][vc_column column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/1" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][divider line_type="Full Width Line" line_thickness="1" divider_color="default" animate="yes"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="full_width_background" full_screen_row_position="middle" equal_height="yes" content_placement="middle" scene_position="top" layer_one_image="6038" layer_two_image="6034" text_color="dark" text_align="left" top_padding="1%" bottom_padding="1%" disable_element="yes" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type=""][vc_column column_padding="padding-3-percent" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="7/12" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][nectar_cascading_images image_1_url="6086" image_1_offset_x_sign="+" image_1_offset_x="0%" image_1_offset_y_sign="-" image_1_offset_y="55%" image_1_rotate_sign="+" image_1_rotate="none" image_1_animation="Grow In" image_1_box_shadow="x_large_depth" image_2_url="6085" image_2_offset_x_sign="+" image_2_offset_x="50%" image_2_offset_y_sign="+" image_2_offset_y="45%" image_2_rotate_sign="+" image_2_rotate="none" image_2_animation="Grow In" image_2_box_shadow="x_large_depth" image_3_url="6084" image_3_offset_x_sign="-" image_3_offset_x="35%" image_3_offset_y_sign="+" image_3_offset_y="30%" image_3_rotate_sign="+" image_3_rotate="none" image_3_animation="Grow In" image_3_box_shadow="x_large_depth" image_4_offset_x_sign="+" image_4_offset_x="0%" image_4_offset_y_sign="+" image_4_offset_y="0%" image_4_rotate_sign="+" image_4_rotate="none" image_4_animation="Fade In" image_4_box_shadow="none" border_radius="none"][/vc_column][vc_column column_padding="padding-6-percent" column_padding_position="left" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="5/12" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_column_text css=".vc_custom_1517444760169{margin-top: 50px !important;margin-bottom: 20px !important;}"]</p>
<h5><span style="color: #999999;">Proiect no.4</span></h5>
<h2>Auchan Ghencea</h2>
<p>[/vc_column_text][nectar_icon_list animate="true" color="default" icon_size="small" icon_style="no-border"][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517435668816-0-5" tab_id="1517435668820-10" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Shop-2" header="Comercial"][/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517434471-1-58" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="42 000 m2" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Background"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517435114965-0-4" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="2015" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Key"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" title="List Item" id="1517434471-2-33" tab_id="1517434693099-10" icon_fontawesome="fa fa-briefcase" header="Auchan Romania"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517435106511-0-9" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="Bulevardul 1 Mai, Bucuresti" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Map2"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][/nectar_icon_list][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="in_container" full_screen_row_position="middle" scene_position="center" text_color="dark" text_align="left" disable_element="yes" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type=""][vc_column column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/1" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][divider line_type="Full Width Line" line_thickness="1" divider_color="default" animate="yes"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="full_width_background" full_screen_row_position="middle" scene_position="top" layer_one_image="6038" layer_two_image="6034" text_color="dark" text_align="left" top_padding="1%" bottom_padding="1%" disable_element="yes" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type=""][vc_column column_padding="padding-3-percent" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="5/12" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_column_text css=".vc_custom_1517444765956{margin-top: 50px !important;margin-bottom: 20px !important;}"]</p>
<h5><span style="color: #999999;">Proiect no.5</span></h5>
<h2>PUZ Sector 6</h2>
<p>[/vc_column_text][nectar_icon_list animate="true" color="default" icon_size="small" icon_style="no-border"][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517435668816-0-5" tab_id="1517435668820-10" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Map" header="Urbanistic"][/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517434471-1-58" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="38 km2" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Background"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" icon_family="iconsmind" title="List Item" id="1517435114965-0-4" tab_id="1517434692723-9" header="2016" icon_iconsmind="iconsmind-Key"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][nectar_icon_list_item icon_type="icon" title="List Item" id="1517434471-2-33" tab_id="1517434693099-10" icon_fontawesome="fa fa-briefcase" header="Primaria Sectorului 6"] [/nectar_icon_list_item][/nectar_icon_list][/vc_column][vc_column enable_animation="true" animation="grow-in" centered_text="true" column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="7/12" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid" delay="100"][nectar_cascading_images image_1_url="6090" image_1_offset_x_sign="+" image_1_offset_x="0%" image_1_offset_y_sign="-" image_1_offset_y="55%" image_1_rotate_sign="+" image_1_rotate="none" image_1_animation="Grow In" image_1_box_shadow="x_large_depth" image_2_url="6091" image_2_offset_x_sign="+" image_2_offset_x="50%" image_2_offset_y_sign="+" image_2_offset_y="35%" image_2_rotate_sign="+" image_2_rotate="none" image_2_animation="Grow In" image_2_box_shadow="x_large_depth" image_3_url="6089" image_3_offset_x_sign="-" image_3_offset_x="35%" image_3_offset_y_sign="+" image_3_offset_y="30%" image_3_rotate_sign="+" image_3_rotate="none" image_3_animation="Grow In" image_3_box_shadow="x_large_depth" image_4_offset_x_sign="+" image_4_offset_x="0%" image_4_offset_y_sign="+" image_4_offset_y="0%" image_4_rotate_sign="+" image_4_rotate="none" image_4_animation="Fade In" image_4_box_shadow="none" border_radius="none"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="in_container" full_screen_row_position="middle" scene_position="center" text_color="dark" text_align="left" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom"][vc_column column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/1" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_custom_heading text="Arhitectura este muzica împietrită" font_container="tag:h1|text_align:center" use_theme_fonts="yes"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="in_container" full_screen_row_position="middle" scene_position="center" text_color="dark" text_align="left" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom"][vc_column column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="1/1" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_raw_js]PHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHQiPiBhbGVydCgiRW50ZXIgeW91ciBqcyBoZXJlISIgKTsgPC9zY3JpcHQ+[/vc_raw_js][/vc_column][/vc_row]</p>
```

Comment: not clear what you want to achieve here. Do you want to add click event to your blue icons?

Comment: May be you should explain the expected functionality. That way fellow member might understand your question.

Comment: You forgot to add your ([mcve]) HTML and css.

Comment: @ArunKumar Yes. I want to sort my gallery with the blue icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to change the html a little bit. it's possible without changing the html but it will be messy.

first for each icon go to the div with class `vc_column-inner` (it will be wrapping the icon) then replace the class with `vc_column-inner filtername` then add an attribute containing the corresponding filter (exemple: for the "Birouri" icon search for div with the class `vc_column-inner` replace the class with `vc_column-inner filtername` then add `data-filtername="birouri"`, do the same for the other icon)

lastly add this javascript

```
<script>
    $('.filtername').on('click', function(){
       if($('a[data-filter=".' + $(this).data('filtername')  + '"]').length){
          $('a[data-filter=".' + $(this).data('filtername')  + '"]').click();
       }
    })
</script>
```

**Without changing the html** 
the ugly way

```
<script>
    var nectar_icon = document.getElementsByClassName('nectar_icon');
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[5].getElementsByTagName('a');
    nectar_icon[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
       a[3].click();
    });
    nectar_icon[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
       a[2].click();
    });
    nectar_icon[2].addEventListener('click', function(){
       a[1].click();
    });
    nectar_icon[4].addEventListener('click', function(){
       a[5].click();
    });
    nectar_icon[5].addEventListener('click', function(){
       a[4].click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My only problem is that the html code is written in shortcode and it's kind off hard to figure it out. I'll find a way to make it work. Thanks

Comment: @TaniaMarin if you can't do the first way do the second one. just copy and past that script

Answer (score 0):

If I catch what you want correctly, You can do with this:

```
$('i.iconsmind-Keypad').click(function(){
$('.js-filter [data-filter=".rezidential"]').trigger('click');
});
```

Every icon have an "icon class" associated that you can use for focus the jquery.
Maybe even more "up" in the html code, in the previous div for example, for have a bigger place to click but With this you  simulate a click in the original link of the portfolio and achieve what you want.